# SQL: Set default value to NULL for all columns without default value

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

The webhosting I use has enabled StrictMode for the Databases. All my php scripts now stopped working because they report I haven't defined a default value for some columns.

As I have a lot of columns in a lot of tables, is there a way to set all the columns with "default value = none" with "default value = NULL" ?
In this way it won't report me the error anymore.

Of course, If there's another (better) way, I am available for it.

I tried looking on the net, but I couldn't find anything suitable for this case.

Comment: `none` is not any special value in MySQL of which I'm aware.  Can you add sample data which explains what you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can alter column

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
 MODIFY COLUMN col datatype  DEFAULT null
```

Comment: Actually the column can be NULL, I just need to set the default value to NULL

Answer (score 0):

A general approach here which should work for each column causing an error would be to set a default value, and then maybe do an update to backfill records missing a value.

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ALTER some_text_column SET DEFAULT 'None';
```

And here is the update:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET some_text_column = 'None' WHERE some_text_column IS NULL;
```

You are not required to do this update, but it might make sense to bring older records missing values in line with what newer records would look like.

Comment: I would like to update all the columns withouta default value (Default value = 'None') in one time, instead of making one query for each column of each table. I need a  quicker way I could say.

Comment: You can't do this without using some dynamic SQL.

Comment: Your second query is setting column value to null instead of setting its default value   to null